# what privileges are required to inherit from table postgresql

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, privileges

As the title already says: What privileges are required to inherit from a table?

I want to create two schemas `core` and `dev` where `core` has a table named `Companies` with `coreuser` as its owner.

Another user, we call it `devuser` has all privileges to access the `dev`schema. How can he inherit from the table `core.Companies` with as few privileges as possible, not even select privileges in the `core`schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a table that inherits from core.companies, devuser must be the owner of core.companies.  Also, devuser must have usage privileges on the schema "core".

I couldn't find this in the docs. I determined the answer through testing.

You *might* be able to work around this by having coreuser create child tables in the dev schema, then either grant privileges to devuser or change ownership to devuser. I *think* devuser will need *some* privileges on core.companies in order to update data, but I could be wrong.